# I'm trying to create a subroutine to draw x's and spaces dependent on two numbers that a user specifies

Tags: c#

I have been given the task to create a subroutine that draws xs and spaces, but I am completely dumbfounded. Here is some additional information that might help:

> Write a subroutine that takes two numbers. The first number indicates the number of spaces that should be displayed and the second indicates the number of Xs that should be displayed. These should both be displayed on the same line. For example drawX(3,4) would display _ _ _ X X X X  (_ indicates a space).

Here is some of the code I have so far (feel free to correct this as I am a semi-beginner to C#)

```
static string spaceRaw = Console.ReadLine();
    static int spaceParsed;

    static string xRaw = Console.ReadLine();
    static int xParsed;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Int32.TryParse(spaceRaw, out spaceParsed);
        Int32.TryParse(xRaw, out xParsed);

        DrawX(spaceParsed, xParsed);
    }

    static void DrawX(int spaces, int x)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a task for learning about for loops, however I would just use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w(v=vs.110).aspx) string constructor.

```
void drawX(int spaces, int x)
{
    Console.write(new String(' ', spaces) + new String('x', x);
}
```

And a for loop version:

```
void drawX(int spaces, int x)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < spaces + x ; i++)
    {
        sb.append((i<spaces) ? " " : "x");
    }
    Console.write(sb.ToString());
}
```

**Note:** Code was written directly here, there might be some mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Can be like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)  
{
    int spaces = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int symbols = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    DrawX(spaces, symbols);
}

static void DrawX(int spaces, int symbols)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < spaces; i++)
        Console.Write(' ');

    for(int i = 0; i < symbols; i++)
        Console.Write('X');

    // line break
    Console.WriteLine(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

String constructor that provides multiple copies of the same character [String Constructor (Char, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`String.PadLeft`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (or corresponding `String.PadRight`) are good options.

If that would be interview question and possibly for "semi-beginner" level you'd probably need to use `for` loop.

Show-off sample - LINQ:

```
static void DrawX(int spaceCount, int xCount)
{
  Console.Write(
    String.Join("",
      Enumerable.Repeat(" ", spaceCount)
      .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("x", xCount))));
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing I would have to "replicate" this for writing x

Comment: @ZoharPeled - yes... original version also did not compile as I typed it in and than LinqPad'ed it... Should be good now.

Comment: @Fuzew - note that Zohar Peled answer is what you likely should copy-paste to your answer... I doubt LINQ solution would be acceptable for any beginner level classes.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Method to return a `string` and in your method you just need to create the particular pattern string and return the same like

```
    static string DrawX(int spaces, int x)
    {
        char[] chrarr = new char[spaces + x];

        for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++)
        {
            chrarr[i] = '_';
        }

        for (int i = spaces - 1; i < chrarr.Length - spaces; i++)
        {
            chrarr[i] = 'X';
        }

        return new string(chrarr);
    }
```